# Is there a way to tell Exceljs to treat undefined as empty and not as zero?

Tags: exceljs

I have an export to excel function based on `ExcelJS`:

```
async function exportToExcel(data: any, layout: Layout){
  const exceljs = await import('exceljs');
  const workbook = new exceljs.Workbook();
  const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("data");
  worksheet.addTable({
    columns: layout.columns,
    name: 'data',
    ref: 'A1',
    rows: data,
    headerRow: true
  });
  // download logic
}
```

The problem is, that when exporting the excel file, all undefined values in numeric columns get converted to zero.

Is there a clean (or rather declarative) way to tell `ExcelJS` to keep such cells empty?